# How can I make the first and last column of a grid fixed-width?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I would like to have a grid with the 1st column of 50px, the last one with 50px too and all the columns in the middle (don't know the amount of columns) to have 1fr.

I've tried with `grid-template-columns: 50px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr)) 50px;` but with no luck.

```css
body {
    font:normal normal 0.8em/0.7em Calibri, Arial, Helvetica;
}
.container {
    background:peru;
    padding:10px;
    display:grid;
    grid-template-columns: 50px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));

    /* grid-template-columns: 50px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr)) 50px; ????*/
}
.container div {
    background:#f0ff00;
    margin:5px;
    padding:5px;
    text-align: center;
    color:#333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">Item 1 - 50px</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item4">Item 4 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item5">Item 5 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item6">Item 6 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item7">Item 7 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item8">Item 8 - 50px</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gb1knso0/

Comment: so you want only 1 row? because with auto-fit you can have many rows

Comment: Yes I need this configuration in only a single row

Answer (score 5):

The problem lies with your `100px` (on narrow layouts it becomes too big for `min` value, forcing grid layout to break).

You should use `calc((100% - 100px)/6)` as `min`.

```css
body{
  font:normal normal 0.8em/0.7em Calibri, Arial, Helvetica;
}
.container{
      background:peru;
      padding:10px;
      display:grid;
      grid-template-columns: 50px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc((100% - 100px)/6), 1fr)) 50px;
      
      /* grid-template-columns: 50px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr)) 50px; ????*/
}

.container div{
  background:#f0ff00;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">Item 1 - 50px</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item4">Item 4 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item5">Item 5 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item6">Item 6 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item7">Item 7 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item8">Item 8 - 50px</div>
</div>
```

... where 6 is the number of columns - 2. You're saying it's *"any number of columns"* but in DOM it's a very exact number of columns. If needed, (re)calculate it when the page is (re)rendered, using JavaScript. Or use `0` as min.

---

Here's a JavaScript script which calculates correct value of `gridTemplateColumns` and applies it:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.container')).forEach(c => {
  const s = `50px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc((100% - 100px)/${c.childElementCount - 2}), 1fr)) 50px`;
  c.style.gridTemplateColumns = s;
  
  // the next bit just displays the styles in the titles. so you can remove from here...
  const h3 = document.createElement('h3');
  h3.innerText = `grid-template-columns: ${s};`;
  c.parentElement.insertBefore(h3, c)
  // ...until here.

});
```

```css
body{
  font:normal normal 0.8em/0.7em Calibri, Arial, Helvetica;
}
h3{
  text-align:center;
}
.container{
  background:peru;
  padding:10px;
  display:grid;
}

.container div{
  background:#f0ff00;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#333333;
}
```

```html
<div class="container opt1">
  <div class="item1">Item 1 - 50px</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item4">Item 4 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item5">Item 5 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item6">Item 6 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item7">Item 7 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item8">Item 8 - 50px</div>
</div>

<div class="container opt2">
  <div class="item1">Item 1 - 50px</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item4">Item 4 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item5">Item 5 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item6">Item 6 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item7">Item 7 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item4">Item 8 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item5">Item 9 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item6">Item 10 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item7">Item 11 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item8">Item 12 - 50px</div>
</div>

<div class="container opt3">
  <div class="item1">Item 1 - 50px</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item7">Item 4 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item8">Item 5 - 50px</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Using 10px as a min value doesn't work neither. Those columns in the middle are created dinamically so i don´t know the exact number of columns, I can use JS to recalculate the layout but I think that there must be a way of doing this only with css.

Comment: What you say doesn't add up. You can see it clearly working here. There must be something else affecting it (maybe some `min-width` or similar). If what you're saying is true, it wouldn't work in my answer as well. Can you post a real example which currently fails with `min` set to `0`? The answer that advises you to have 3 columns grid and put another grid in the middle column is quite solid, if you ask me. It basically can't fail. the left and right will always stay `50px`.

Comment: Yes, the option to wrap the middle columns is a nice solution but I can not do that. Here are other options that are not working https://jsfiddle.net/dte14q53/

Comment: Let's use a bigger hammer: `Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.container')).forEach(c => c.style.gridTemplateColumns = '50px repeat(auto-fit, minmax(calc((100% - 100px)/' + (c.childElementCount - 2) + '), 1fr)) 50px');` - https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/1jc4ymrd/3/

Answer (score 0):

I did it with display flex. By giving them all `flex:1` they're the same with, and for the first and last one we set a width:

```css
.container{
      background:peru;
      padding:10px;
      display:flex;
}

.container div{
  flex: 1;
  background:#f0ff00;
  margin:5px;
  padding:5px;
  text-align: center;
  color:#333333;
}
.container div:first-child,
.container div:last-child{
  width: 50px;
  flex: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item1">Item 1 - 50px</div>
  <div class="item2">Item 2 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item3">Item 3 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item4">Item 4 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item5">Item 5 - 1fr</div>
  <div class="item8">Item 8 - 50px</div>
</div>
```

Please note:
- I've removed two items to give a better demo,
- the  first/last item are 60 width because of the padding. If you 50 as end result, either make it `width:40px` or `box-sizing:border-box`

Comment: I'm considering in using flex but I need to solve it using grid rght now.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grid-template-columns: 50px auto 50px` for the `container` div and then put the inner unknown number of divs into another div and set `display: grid` of that div to contain the the child divs.

Working JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7mgnaf5L/

P.S. You can use `display: inline` for the child divs if you want them on one line.

Edit 1:
Try setting the widths of 50px children and set `grid-auto-flow: column` for the main div.

https://jsfiddle.net/1p4sdt9y/

Comment: I can't add an extra div inside.

Comment: The thing there is that you're setting a fixed width to the content, not to the column, look https://i.imgur.com/f8kwjs2.png